# 450 HTTP ERROR on Search result page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

We are getting an error on the Search Result page. when we hint homepage the site is working fine.

First when we land on the site and search something then the Search Result page is showing properly but after some hours when we reload the same page again we are getting a **`450 HTTP ERROR`**. is there anyone who faced this same error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We bumped into this issue today and discovered that our hosting firm's WAF had a rule that prevented direct URL access to search results pages as a search abuse prevention. Maybe check with your hosting provider to see if that's the case.